# Upload a text file to the server

Tags: django

I am making a kind of inventory where the ids of the existing items are written in a text file and I only need to upload the text file to the server.
I have uploaded videos, images and TIFFs to the same server without problems, but I have no idea why it is not working now!

My model:

```
def inventory_file_path(instance, file_name):

    name = instance.date.__str__()+'.txt'
    path = concatenate_paths([inventory_folder, name])
    return path


class Inventory(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField('Date', null=True, blank=True)
    crosses = models.ManyToManyField(Cross,verbose_name='Crosses scanned', null=True, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=inventory_file_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

The form:

```
class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        exclude = [InventoryFields.crosses]

        file = forms.FileField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InventoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        end_year = datetime.date.today().year + 1
        self.fields[InventoryFields.date].widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(start_year, end_year))
        self.file = forms.FileField()
```

The views:

```
def new_inventory(request):

    if request.method == GET:
        inv = Inventory()
        inv.date = datetime.date.today()
        form = InventoryForm(instance=inv)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InventoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():       
            inv = form.save()
```

when I check the database, the inventory object is being saved and it's date is right but the file is not uploaded. further more, the upload_to method is not being called